# Matrix Addition in Python - list

Tags: python, list, matrix

I'm trying to write Matrix Addition function using Python.

Here is the code I've been trying, but it gives me a list index error and I cannot figure out why.

```
def matrixADD(A,B):
Z = []
#TODO
for i in range(0,len(A)):
    for column in range(0, len(A)):
        result = A[i][column] + B[i][column]
        Z[i][column] = (result)
return Z
```

using the following lists:

```
A = [[2,4], [7,0], [6,3]]
B = [[3,1], [-1,8], [-3, 3]]
```

So in theory, A[0][0] + B[0][0] would equal 5, and I would want to add that value to position Z[0][0].

However I keep receiving the error: IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: Can you post the full traceback of your error?

Comment: Your "matrices" are 3 x 2 matrices.  But you are indexing over them with i, j in {0, 1, 2}.  You get an `IndexError` when `j=2` (third, nonexistent column). Also, you are inconsistently using `column` and `j`.  Why not use [`numpy.matrix`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html)?

Comment: your inner loop is iterating three times because A holds 3 lists.  Switch iner loop to len(A[0])

Comment: Also, are your matrices guaranteed to be square?  Your code is assuming that.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 88, in <module>
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 63, in main
  File "/Applications/WingIDE.app/Contents/MacOS/src/debug/tserver/_sandbox.py", line 19, in matrixADD
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: The matrices ARE guaranteed to be square, I'm leaving out some non-essential bits of the program. I believe dasmith nailed it though, the big problem was from iterating the inner loop too many times.

Thanks to everyone who helped! My code works again :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
>>> A = [[2,4], [7,0], [6,3]]
>>> B = [[3,1], [-1,8], [-3, 3]]
>>> Z = [map(sum, zip(*t)) for t in zip(A, B)]
>>> Z
[[5, 5], [6, 8], [3, 6]]
```

As for how you could fix your current code:

```
Z = []
for i in range(len(A)):
    row = []
    for j in range(len(A[i])):
        row.append(A[i][j] + B[i][j])
    Z.append(row)
```

The important parts here being that you cannot just assign to `Z[i][j]` unless that row/column already exists, so you need to construct each inner list separately and append them to `Z`.  Also the inner loop needs to end at the length of a row, so I changed `range(len(A))` to `range(len(A[i]))`.

Answer (score 0):

`len(A) = 3` but you matrix have dimension 3x2 so when you try to access A[2][2] (because column is between 0 and len(A)) you are out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

For `column` you are using range 0 to len(A) (which is 3).  A[i][2] will be out of range, because A[i]'s length is only 2.

Try using column range to end a len(A[i]) instead of len(A):

```
def matrixADD(A,B):
    Z = []
    #TODO
    for i in range(0,len(A)):
        for column in range(0, len(A[i])):
            result = A[i][column] + B[i][column]
            Z[i][j] = (result)
    return Z
```