# How to addition two matrixes using nested for loop?

Tags: python, matlab

I am new to python but I have some working experience with matlab. I have a specific question regarding how to save calculation of nested for loop to matrix variable `x(i,j)`.

Let say `x=1:10` and `y=1:5`. Now if I need to make the sum of individual elements of x with individual elements of y, then in matlab I have command like

```
sum=0;

for i=1:length(x)
    for j=1:length(y)
        sum(i,j)=x(i)+y(j);
    end
end
```

Now I need to convert the above routine to python. How can it be possible?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matrix Addition in Python - list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22333896/matrix-addition-in-python-list)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension. This will produce the same output as your Matlab code.

```
x = range(1, 11)
y = range(1, 6)

s = [[xx + yy for yy in y] for xx in x]

print(s)
```